# Running testng.xml via maven gives error

Tags: java, maven-2, webdriver, pom.xml

I want to run my testng.xml file via pom.xml but it is giving . However testng.xml working fine when Run as testng suite. The error which I am getting is:(sorry for pasting entire console o/p but I didnt want to take chance).

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myproj 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server-standalone:jar:2.33.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproj ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproj ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.2:test (default-test) @ myproj ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\workspace\myproj\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 17; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".; nested exception is org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 17; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 17; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 17; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "name".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
    ... 10 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.826s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 03 20:15:45 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.2:test (default-test) on project myproj: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to D:\workspace\myproj\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

When I expand **slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar** under maven dependencies I observe that this class is there but I don't understand if it is there and mentioned correctly in pom.xml than why it is failed to load. Please let me know where am I missing. 
 
**Pom.xml is : I right clicked on it and tried running it as Maven test and Maven build(w/o specifying goal)but got no luck it kept on giving same error**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproj.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myproj</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.33.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>

            <version>1.7.5</version>

        </dependency>



    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Output directory for the report -->
                    <outputDir>${project.basedir}/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir>
                    <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                    <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
                    <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>testng-xslt-plugin</id>
            <url>http://www.cosminaru.ro/maven/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: I think it's just a warning..what happens after scanning for projects line?

Comment: @niharika_neo edited the error that I have got. It said that I didn't have resources directory,so I have created one(empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the 6.9 version of testng is still not available and so maven is unable to fetch the dependency.  I think the last release is 6.8.5. Change the version of your testng dependency to 6.8.5 and try.

Comment: I have changed the testng version to 6.8.5 but error is still there. I have updated please take a look

Comment: The error is in ur testng.xml...you have been changing your question..someone referring to this thread would never get any help out of it..I would suggest create another thread for a different error or add data to the thread instead of replacin...u wud need to paste ur testng.xml contents for someone to help u with the new error..

Comment: but when I run testng.xml as testng suite it runs fine

Comment: Wats at line number 6 in the XML? Also what version of the testng plugin do u have?

Comment: Hi Niharika, in line number 6 in my testng.xml quotes were missing . So testng.xml was giving error. I am so sorry for keep you bugging for such a silly typp mistake. Many thanks for your efforts.